# Async navigation in Prism Scoped Region

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, prism

I have a WPF project based upon PRISM 6.1.0
Shell exposes TabControl as a "MainRegion".
I need to display several views that loads data from the database. Data loading process takes time, and UI remains frozen.
I've tried to RUN this procedd async like this

```
await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, "FirstView", parameters);
                RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, "SecondView", parameters);
                ....
                RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, "LastView", parameters);
            });
```

but nothing happens, UI stays frozen untill last view will be loaded and only then displays all views in TabControl...

Is there any way to load Views asynchronously?

Comment: in addition of what Brian said,
When one process take so much long time and UI thread needs to stay responsive while process is running, the most common method to place a long running process on a separate thread.
In WPF there are mostly use technique is  Backgroundworker. Backgroundworker is mostly use in multithreading applications.
You have to integrate Busyindicator while Data loading, Busyindicater comes with WPF extended toolkit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to your View first, and then have your View async load its data.  You can show a busy indicator control to show something is being loaded in the background.  When the data has been loaded, the busy indicator will hide and the View will display the newly loaded data.

Comment: So it's not possible to get all Views async? Only to Navigate to view, load data async, then go to second etc... ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by navigating to 3 views in a row?

Comment: My project consist of TabControl where each tab is a ScopedRegion and represents a set of different tabs that differ by type of data. Each ScopedRegion may contain different set of views. Im my code i check what Views should be in ScopedRegion and navigating to them one by one in a row.

Comment: In that case, navigate to your views, and have your data load async.  When the data is ready, the views will show it.  You can't create a view on a different thread and show it on the UI thread.  Controls have thread affinity, and it is just not possible.